# Lack of support for more lines

Tags: line, nsis

More lines are not typed in the output file

Hello . I want to use two hundred and eighty lines in the code below, but only sixty or seventy lines are typed in the file and the rest of the lines are not typed. I do not want to use other methods. I just want to know the reason why all 280 lines are not typed in the file. Thank you for any help

Example

nsExec::exec `"$SYSDIR\cmd.exe" /c "\

Echo WScript.Sleep(50)>> "SendKey.bat"&\ ; line 1

Echo WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("^{a}");>>"SendKey.bat"&\ ;line 2

Echo WScript.Sleep(50)>> "SendKey.bat"&\ ;line 3

Echo WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{del}");>>"SendKey.bat"&\ ;line 4

; line 280
"`

Answer (score 0):

Windows has commandine length limit and NSIS also has a string length limit.

Just use NSIS functions

```
ClearErrors
FileOpen $0 $INSTDIR\file.bat w
IfErrors done
FileWrite $0 "line 1 $\n"
FileWrite $0 "line 2 $\n"
FileClose $0
done:
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and I hope you will be successful in all stages of life